# video mp4 not loading

Tags: video, mp4

i got strange problem i added this player to my website. 
And few videos works , and few not. what may be the cause of that, do any1 knows ? The first three works fine, the last one nope. I got similar on other pages

```
    <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
    controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="http://serwer1340051.home.pl/test/drogi_images/chajzer.png"
 data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
     <source src="http://serwer1340051.home.pl/test/dtvn_GDDKiA_chajzer_14.12.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
 </video>
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
   controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="http://serwer1340051.home.pl/test/drogi_images/tvn_21_12.png"
    data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
  <source src="http://serwer1340051.home.pl/test/ddtvn_GDDKiA_21.12.mp4" type='video/mp4' /> 
  </video>
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="http://serwer1340051.home.pl/test/drogi_images/tvn_28_12.png"
 data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
   <source src="http://serwer1340051.home.pl/test/DD_TVN_GDDKiA_28.12.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
  </video>
  <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
    controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="http://serwer1340051.home.pl/test/drogi_images/20130111_TVN_09_46_95090294.png"
     data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
    <source src="http://serwer1340051.home.pl/test/20130111_TVN_09_46_95090294.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
 </video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codec in the last video is `MPEG-4 Video (mp4v)` and it is not supported by browsers.

I have checked `DD_TVN_GDDKiA_28.12.mp4` codec which is `H264`. This one is fine.

Check this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support) to know the supported formats by browser.

If you want to convert your `MP4` file, use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).

---

Here is a **command line example** :

```
ffmpeg -i 20130111_TVN_09_46_95090294.mp4 -vcodec libx264 output.mp4
```